# Make floats flow over instead of dropping below eachother

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-float

I've got a number of div's with `float:left;`, of course they show up next to eachother but except for the floating div's wich don't fit in the wrapper div anymore.

I need the divs to stay next to eachother and flow over on the x-axis. I know it could be done by setting a fixed width to the wrapper and wrapping the wrapper in another wrapper but the width isn't static and prefer not to use a script to calculate the width.

The situation is:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="floatleft"></div>
  <div class="floatleft"></div>
  <div class="floatleft"></div>
</div>

//Wrapper WITHOUT fixed width
#wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.floatleft{
  float:left;
  width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have fixed width on html and body? That could force the divs to go below. If you do try removing it.

Comment: Floats just don't work like that, you'll have to resort to something like absolute positioning.

Comment: You could have a wrapper inside the wrapper with an absurdly large width so that this wouldn't be a problem. Not elegant, but should work. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AUwqS/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap` http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/EbAFw/

```
<ul id="wrap">
    <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li>    
</ul>

#wrap {margin:20px;width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap}
li {display:inline-block;width:100px;height:100%;background:#5AA4D7;color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif}
```

The only catch is the markup will be white-space sensitive.

Edit: this works cross-browser, with IE7 and below just needing a `*display:inline;zoom:1` at the end of the `li` rule.